# How to calculate out-of-sample and in-sample Sharpe Ratio?

Tags: sharpe-ratio

I am conducting a backtest on different investment strategies and would like to calculate

(i) the out-of-sample Sharpe ratio and

(ii) the in-sample Sharpe ratio according to *"Optimal Versus Naive Diversification:How Inefficient is the 1/N Portfolio Strategy?"* (http://faculty.london.edu/avmiguel/DeMiguel-Garlappi-Uppal-RFS.pdf p.14).

My approach for (i) is the following: First I derived rolling windows for M monthly returns in order to determine the investment weights. Then I invest in M+1 according to the derived weights in order to obtain the out-of-sample return. This is done until the end of my investment period. To get the excess returns I subtract the returns with the respective risk-free rate. Then I take the sample average of the excess returns and divide it by the standard deviation of excess returns to get the out-of-sample Sharpe ratio. Is this correct?

For (ii) I really do not understand how to do it. According to the paper the whole investment period should be taken to derive the optimal weights. Having obtained these weights, with which return should I multiply them? In the paper it says, that the whole series of excess returns is taken. Does this mean that I have to multiply each return with these weights? I'm really struggling here and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Yes, for (ii) you are allowed to cheat a little bit and find the optimal weights over the whole period $w^*$ and then you go back to period 1, and multiply the returns with these weight, then you go to period 2 and again multiply these same weights with the returns in period 2 and so on. You are using weights that were not known at the time, so that is why it is called in sample results, which are not completely realistic.

Comment: Thank you very much! And my approach for (i) is correct as well? My derivations of the optimal portfolio weights are based on the "normal" returns and not the excess returns. I'm a bit confused because in the paper the portfolio weigths are derived based on excess returns (p.7/8). Does this make any difference?

Comment: TBH I asked myself the same question when I read the DeMiguel paper, and I don't know the answer to that. It *might* make a difference because interest rates are not constant... Need an answer from an expert...

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your time!!